# My django generic DetailView not displaying queries

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, detailview

This is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name = "blog-home"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name = "post-detail"),
    path('about/', views.about, name = "blog-about"),
]
```

I am importing PostDetailView to use with my model Post
Here is my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    # Default naming Convection: <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    template_name = "blog/home.html"
    context_object_name = "posts"
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

#This is the my Detail View
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

My Template name is post_detail.html just as the django convection specifies.
Here is the error that comes to my console

```
Not Found: /post/1/
[10/Aug/2020 03:44:27] "GET /post/1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1728
```

While loading the home page, it displays all posts in a list as from my list view.
This is the post_detail.html

```
<!-- Template Inheritance -->
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{%block content%}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded ">
            <div class="">
                <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
                <small>By {{ object.author }} on {{object.date_posted}}</small>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <p>{{object.content}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you sure you that you have `Post` instance with PK=1 in your database?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I have two posts.

Comment: its not about ***how may***, its about, ***how exact***. I am sure that you will never have two `Post` instance with `PK=1`

Comment: There was a problem with the user table. I had earlier deleted a few users and their post in effect. As I added more user and post, Primary Key 1 to 4 were empty for the deleted users. Accesing PK=1 would never have worked. I ran a the shell and checked if I had object with PK=1.